# if a pointer is freed, how about the content it points to? will it be influenced or not?

Tags: c, pointers

as in the following code:

```
typedef struct list {
  ...
  ...
  struct Data *data;
} List;

List* list = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List))
struct Data* data = (struct Data*) malloc(sizeof(struct Data));

 .....// here fill the `data`

list->data = data;
 ....
 struct Data* new_data = list->data;
 free(list); /* my question is: will this `free` influence `new_data` */
```

I have a structure list, in which there is a pointer, which points to some content,
if the ist is freed, the pointer is also freed
how about `new_data`, is it influenced or not?
thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The contents of `new_data` will not be affected.  It will still be valid after the "parent" data is freed.

Answer (score 5):

No, the memory allocated to `new_data` is unaffected. Each `malloc()` must have an accompanying `free()` to release the allocated memory.

Answer (score 4):

"free()" is freeing only the "list" memory, not the memory on which it's members are pointing.